# JS FileTransfert return Http 411

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cordova

I am trying to update the profile picture, which is working on local server but not the remote server, 
On the last one I receive a `Http 411` response

```
function imageReceived(imageURI) { // this is done after taking a picture
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.fileName = 'profilePic.jpg';
      options.headers = {Authorization: 'Token token=' + profile.accessToken};

  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload(imageURI,
     url("/api/v1/update_avatar"), // url() is a function that returns the full path
     function(result) {
       alert(result);

     },
     function(error) {
         alert( JSON.stringify(error));
     },
     options);
}
```

PS :

- `profile` is a class I already have, and accessToken have a right value
- Local Server is HTTP and remote server is HTTPS, does this make a difference ?

What am I doing wrong or missing ??

Any help would be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the `Content-Length` header with the request.

From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html:

```
411 Length Required

The server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content- Length. The client MAY repeat the request if it adds a valid Content-Length header field containing the length of the message-body in the request message.
```

Comment: TY, forgive me to ask, in this case what's the value of Content-Length ?? related to the file name or file size ??

Comment: The value should be the number of bytes the file consists of. You can get it in PHP with `filesize()`.

Comment: Still have the 411 event with Content-Type and Content-Length, here is the header : `options.headers = {'Authorization': 'Token token=' + profile.accessToken, 'Content-Length': file.size, 'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'};`

Comment: Actually the problem is related to the Appgyver Steroids itself, and It wouldn't work without this so I'm going to accept it as right answer

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to discuss it with your hosting company, as you can tell by [this post](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E411.html).

> The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream
>   sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot)
>   should include a 'Content-Length' specification. This is typically
>   used only for HTTP methods that result in the placement of data on the
>   Web server, not the retrieval of data from it.
>
> Fixing 411 errors - general
>
> This error seldom occurs in most Web traffic, particularly when the
>   client system is a Web browser. The problem can only be resolved by
>   examining what your client system is trying to do then discussing with
>   your ISP why the Web server expects a 'Content-Length' specification.